# Add a Total Row and converting into percentages

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with information about people's  work condition and neighbourhood.

I have to display a chart of information in percentages like this:

```
Neighbourhood Total  Employed Unemployed Inactive
Total          100     50         25        25
1              100     45         30        25
2              100     55         20        25
```

To do that, the code that I've made so far is:

```
   select neighbourhood, Count (*) as Total,
   Count(Case when (condition = 1) then 'employed' end) as employed,
   Count (case when (condition = 2) then 'unemployed' end) as unemployed,
   Count (Case when (condition =3) then 'Inactive' end) as Inactive

   from table
   group by  neighbourhood
   order by  neighbourhood
```

the output for that code is (the absolut numbers are made up, they dont result in the percentages above):

```
   Neighbourhood Total  Employed Unemployed Inactive
   1              600     300        200        100
   2              450     220        159        80
```

So, I have to turn the absolut numbers in percentages and add the Total Row (suming the values from the neighbourhoods) but I all my efforts were a failure. I can't solve how to add that Total row nor how to have that total for each neighbourhood for calculating the percentages

I started studying SQL just two weeks ago so I apologize for any inconvenience. I tried my best to keep it simple (in my database  are 15 neighbourhoods and it's ok if they are labeled by numbers)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to UNION to the add the total row

```
   select 'All' as neighbourhood, Count (*) as Total,
   Count(Case when (condition = 1) then 1 end) as employed,
   Count (case when (condition = 2) then 1 end) as unemployed,
   Count (Case when (condition =3) then 1 end) as Inactive

   from table

   UNION all

   select neighbourhood, Count (*) as Total,
   Count(Case when (condition = 1) then 1 end) as employed,
   Count (case when (condition = 2) then 1 end) as unemployed,
   Count (Case when (condition =3) then 1 end) as Inactive

   from table
   group by  neighbourhood
   order by  neighbourhood
```

Comment: I have an error message: sintax invalid for integer "all"

Comment: when i run the code above union, the neighbourhood column appear as "unknown". For the code below the union, neighbourhood are integers  (that is ok, the hoods are named with numbers)

Comment: You cant have integers and string on the same column, So  you need convert neighbouhood to string

Answer (score 1):

You can add the total rows using `grouping sets`:

```
select neighbourhood, Count(*) as Total,
       sum((condition = 1)::int) as employed,
       sum((condition = 2)::int) as unemployed,
       sum((condition = 3)::int) as Inactive
from table
group by grouping sets ( (neighbourhood), () )
order by  neighbourhood;
```

If you want averages *within* each row, then use `avg()` rather than `sum()`.